# Excel issue that I dont see

Tags: string, excel

I want to do some normal excel stuff so just a sub string of this string

```
Documents/Z_Documentation/PDF/HTLT_105_492_VTR631-1.PDF
```

All that I want is to get everything after the last **"/"**

What I do

```
=RIGHT(C3,LEN(C3)-FIND("/",C3,1))
```

But I always receive the same error message

**We found a problem with this formula 
you type  =1+1, cells shows 2 .....**

Comment: to show the countless possibilities here: `{=RIGHT(A1,MIN(IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,ROW(1:99)),1)="/",ROW(1:99)-1)))}` also will do :P

Answer (score 0):

Calculating stuff after you type "=" and hit enter is a normal excel behavior.

As for extracting the file name, you can use this formula:

`=MID(C3,FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(C3,"/","*",LEN(C3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3,"/",""))))+1,LEN(C3))`

By using `LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3,"/",""))))` you are actually find the number of instances of the "/", which are three in your case. Then you search and replace for the third instance of " / " with " * ". Finally you search for the " * " in the result add 1 to it to get the next symbol and call the sub-string function "MID"

Answer (score 0):

Even this will do:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C3,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(C3))),LEN(C3)))
```

***TRIM*** function removes all spaces from text except for single spaces between words. See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9) for details.

***REPT*** function repeats text a given number of times. See [this](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/REPT-function-04C4D778-E712-43B4-9C15-D656582BB061) for details.

Comment: This consumes more memory

Comment: @ДеянДобромиров I am not sure if that is true... just by the way excel calculates, accessing data takes more time that alternating it... this way Mrig's formula may be faster in some cases... I've done both your formulas for one full column and then took time several times with calculatefull... your formula took ~0.67s while Mrig only needs ~0.52s